# How to determine if mysql is using directory under mounted directory?

Tags: mount, mysql, raid, automounting

I currently have MySQL using `/home/foo/data/database` as its datadir. With `/home/foo/data/database` being a mounted raid 1 array. The problem I am having is that every once in awhile on boot MySQL is starting before the raid array is mounted to `/home/foo/data/database`, as a result MySQL uses `/home/foo/data/database` on the root drive for its datadir instead of the mounted raid array. This is causing issues as everything appears to be fine when I look at the raid array status, mounted partitions, and MySQL. Except that my MySQL database is empty as all the data is on the raid array.

Is there a way to determine if MySQL is using the the root drive path instead of the raid array? That way I at least know if this problem has occurred so I can restart MySQL to fix the issue.

```
foo@foo:~$ lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0              7:0    0 110.6M  1 loop  /snap/core/12834
loop1              7:1    0  27.8M  1 loop  /snap/wifi-ap/355
sda                8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
└─md0              9:0    0 465.7G  0 raid1 /home/foo/data/database
sdb                8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─md0              9:0    0 465.7G  0 raid1 /home/foo/data/database
sdc                8:32   0  59.6G  0 disk
└─sdc3             8:35   0  59.6G  0 part
  ├─foo_vg-root 253:0    0  16.2G  0 lvm   /
  ├─foo_vg-data 253:1    0  42.5G  0 lvm   /home/foo/data
  └─foo_vg-swap 253:2    0     1G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

```
foo@foo:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system>         <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/foo-root    /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/foo_vg-data /home/foo/data  ext4    defaults          0       0
/dev/mapper/foo_vg-swap none            swap    sw                0       0

/dev/md0        /home/foo/data/database   ext4  defaults,nofail,discard   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to edit your systemd startup script to include

```
After home-foo-data-database.mount
```

in the [Service] section. You can also create the file

```
/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf
```

to add the condition without touching your original service file. Assumes that the service is named `mysql`

Other option available if you're writing your own startup script. `mountpoint /home/foo/data/database` will return true if a filesystem is mounted there, false otherwise. Test the mountpoint and either exit or loop until true is returned.